# About MySQL stored procedures

Tags: mysql, .net, stored-procedures

i am currently working with a MySQL database through Workbench and a visualbasic.net desktop program. The question is, is it possible for me to create one stored procedure that will, for example, handle all the "INSERT INTO" queries for the whole program? Or would it be better for me to write a new stored procedure  for each table that i want to insert/select/delete etc?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: it's possible, but there's a high chance it isn't a very good idea, unless the number of INSERT queries is you need happens to be only one :-). Better to keep different bits of functionality separate usually, it's generally more maintainable and probably less error-prone. Write a stored procedure to do a particular business task. It might involve several queries or it might involve one, depending on the task and what needs to be achieved to get the desired result. But really how you structure your code is a matter of opinion, also your personal taste, standards, business requirements etc.

Comment: It is _possible_, but it is such a horrible idea that you need a new word for "horrible".  The maintenance overhead would quickly become a nightmare, and you gain nothing practical.  Even "I know where the code is" falls apart, because the seven seconds you save not having to look for the stored procedure is quickly lost to finding the right section among seventeen thousand lines of SP code.